# Set all lines to be the same width (add white spaces)

Tags: scala, text, grid

I'm currently trying to make a grid out of my text. If I have a text like this:

```
AAAAA\n
BBBBBBB\n
EEEE\n
CCCCCC\n
```

I want it to be like this:

```
AAAAA  \n
BBBBBBB\n
EEEE   \n
CCCCCC \n
```

I made this simple function that does just that, but it's definitely not the way to go in my opinion (it's way too long):

```
 private def fixText(lines: Vector[String]): Vector[String] = {
    val fixedLines = for(i <- lines) yield {
      val addSpaces = " " * (lines.maxBy(_.length).length - i.length)
      i + addSpaces
    }
    fixedLines
  }
```

Is there a way to make this in just a single line in Scala?

Comment: i also suffer from the temptation to make everything a single line, but it's not always a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that:

```
"aaa".padTo(5, 'A') // aaaAA
```

you could do:

```
val input = "AAAAA\nBBBBBBB\nEEEE\nCCCCCC\n".split("\n")
val max = input.map(_.size).max // BBBBBBB => 7
input.map(s => s.padTo(max, ' ')).mkString("\n")
```

which first gets the maximum length of an element after splitting lines. And then pads all lines with the appropriate number of characters before joining back.

Not exactly one line, but a one-liner would probably mean losses in performance by computing things several times:

```
val input = "AAAAA\nBBBBBBB\nEEEE\nCCCCCC\n"
input.split("\n").map(s => s.padTo(input.split("\n").map(_.size).max, ' ')).mkString("\n")
```